# Elasticsearch Multi-Match Query with AND operator for the tokens generated by Hyphenation_decompounder token filter

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I used [hyphenation_decompounder](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-hyp-decomp-tokenfilter.html) for German language and followed the example as mentioned in the documentation. So far so good. it works!. The text `kaffeetasse` is tokenized into `kaffee` and `tasse`.

The concern arose when I use **multi-match** query for *kaffeetasse* to find documents where kaffee AND tasse both matches. It seems that multi-match uses **OR** for the tokens generated by   hyphenation_decompounder filter instead of given Operator("AND") in multi-match query. Here is my Test-case

Mapping

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/testidx" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "settings": {    "index": {      "analysis": {        "analyzer": {          "index": {            "type" : "custom",            "tokenizer": "whitespace",            "filter": [ "lowercase" ]          },          "search": {            "type" : "custom",            "tokenizer": "whitespace",            "filter": [ "lowercase", "hyph" ]          }        },        "filter": {          "hyph": {            "type": "hyphenation_decompounder",            "hyphenation_patterns_path": "analysis/de_DR.xml",            "word_list": ["kaffee", "zucker", "tasse"],            "only_longest_match": true,            "min_subword_size": 4          }        }      }    }  },    "mappings" : {      "properties" : {        "title" : {          "type" : "text",          "analyzer": "index",          "search_analyzer": "search"        },        "description" : {          "type" : "text",          "analyzer": "index",          "search_analyzer": "search"        }      }    }  }'
```

Document id=1

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testidx/_doc/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "title" : "Kaffee",  "description": "Milch Kaffee tasse"}'
```

Document id=2

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/testidx/_doc/2" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "title" : "Kaffee",  "description": "Latte Kaffee Becher"}'
```

Multi-Match query

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testidx/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "query": {    "multi_match": {      "query": "kaffeetasse",      "fields": ["title", "description"],      "operator": "and",     "type": "cross_fields",     "analyzer": "search"    }  }}'
```

My expectation is that elasticsearch should return only single document with **id=1** as it has `kaffee` **AND** `tasse` in its fields but it returns both documents as both have `kaffee` **OR** `tasse` text.

Elasticsearch: **7.9.2**

`de_DR.xml` downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/offo/files/offo-hyphenation/1.2/offo-hyphenation_v1.2.zip/download as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Struggling with the same issue. We work on an e-commerce search with denglish words like `Tablethalterung`. To decompound that, we use a domain specific word list which split the denglish compound word correct. But the result is useless, because we get the all documents which contains `tablet` or `halter` and not tablet and halter
Our current search based on ES 2 handels this as expected. 
Have you found a solution, yet?

Comment: @ThomasHaarbach, Haven't found any Elasticsearch based solution. As far of now, Tokenizing the query with Lucene hyphenation decompounder before sending to ES is seems to be a viable workaround.

Comment: hmm and this works. I've tried it with a es analysies round trip and i  got also bad results, because the original term is in the token stream e.g. [kaffeetasse, kaffee, tasse].
Openend this topic https://discuss.elastic.co/t/german-compound-words-in-an-e-commerce-search/270280

Answer (score 2):

Elasticsearch returns both documents because it applies `operator` parameter **to the original query** `kaffeetasse`, not to the tokens `kaffee` and `tasse` produced by analyzer. Such behavior described in [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) for `match` query:

> **operator** (Optional, string) Boolean logic used to interpret *text in the `query` value*.

Since the original query is one word, the `operator` parameter has no sense.

As a workaround you can perform your search in two steps:

1. Analyze your original query string with [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

   ```
    curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testidx/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"analyzer": "search", "text": "kaffeetasse"}'
   ```
2. Use tokens received from `search` analyzer as words for `multi_match` query with `operator` parameter set to `and` and `analyzer` parameter set to `whitespace` (to prevent already analyzed tokens to be analyzed again with `search` analyzer):

   ```
    curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/testidx/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "query": {"multi_match": {"query": "kaffee tasse", "fields": ["title", "description"], "operator": "and", "type": "cross_fields", "analyzer": "whitespace"}}}'
   ```

Comment: I am concerned by _additional time_ taken by the round trip of executing **Step-1**. I was thinking to extract the Lucene _hyphenation decompounder_ functionality and pre-process the query before sending it to Elasticsearch.